# Which Democratic Presidential candidates favored making illegal entry only a civil violation?

Tags: united-states, law, illegal-immigration, democratic-primary

Under Federal law, illegal entry into the United States is both a criminal violation and a civil violation.  But historically, most people caught crossing the border illegally were not criminally prosecuted for illegal entry.  Instead, most people just went through civil deportation proceedings.  This changed under the Trump Administration, when then-Attorney General Jeff Sessions implemented a "zero tolerance policy", requiring the Department of Justice to criminally prosecute every single person caught crossing the border illegally.  This resulted in large numbers of children being separated from their parents.  So in the June 26 Democratic Presidential Debate, then-candidate Julián Castro [proposed](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2019/06/27/transcript-night-one-first-democratic-debate-annotated/) that section 1325 of the Immigration and Nationality Act, which made illegal entry a criminal violation, be repealed:

> My plan also includes getting rid of Section 1325 of the Immigration and Nationality Act, to go back to the way we used to treat this when somebody comes across the border, not to criminalize desperation, to treat that as a civil violation.  And here's why it's important. We see all of this horrendous family separation. They use that law, Section 1325, to justify under the law separating little children from their families.  And so I want to challenge every single candidate on this stage to support the repeal of Section 1325.... Let's be very clear. The reason that they're separating these little children from their families is that they're using Section 1325 of that act which criminalizes coming across the border to incarcerate the parents and then separate them.

Now Castro has since dropped out of the race.  But my question is, which 2020 Democratic Presidential Candidates supported repealing section 1325?

Comment: Can you clarify how long ago "historically" is?

Comment: @bobsburner Illegal entry has been a federal crime since 1929.  In all that time criminal prosecutions of illegal entry have been relatively low.  There was a small uptick during Bush’s Operation Streamline, but it was only the Trump Administration which decided to criminally prosecute all illegal entries.

Comment: As a beside the point I really do not understand the difference. If you sneak across the border, illegally, what criminal response is relevant? imprisonment? Then they are, de facto, immigrated, unless guantanamo bay gets a very handsome expansion. They can be deported just as efficiently (perhaps more so) in a civil process. Criminal proceedings usually protect the accused to a substantially higher degree. Which means that in sum it'll take longer. So what all the brouhaha is about, is hard to see, at least with non-american eyes.

Comment: @StianYttervik not american either, but from what I understand the people used to be deported as a family and people had an "oh well, we'll try again next month" mentality. Now the families are separated and parents imprisoned while they await trial; the conditions for the kids aren't great either. Their aim is to make the experience of getting caught much worse so it serves as a deterrent to illegal immigration. I also sense a lot of spite: even if it would be easier and cheaper for the US to simply deport the illegal immigrants, they want to punish them for trying.

Comment: @AlexandreAubrey Ah. That does sound reasonable. Retributionism.

Comment: The question and some of the comments have false and misleading information.  Prosecutions for illegal entry do happen, but the majority of cases causing so call separation of children occurs due to the families requesting asylum or not showing paper work that the children are family.  I feel I have to remind everyone that the separation has occurred in the Obama administration as well.  What has actually changed is the catch and release program where the families requesting asylum were released into the public with a promise to come back for their hearing. Now they have to stay in custody.

Comment: The whole reason there was "catch and release" is because there weren't enough beds for all the people who got caught, and even illegal immigrants have due process rights.  Trump decided to not build courts and detention centers with the 25B the congressional leaders offered for border security.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan can you put that info into the question somewhere?

Comment: I would point out that someone charged with a criminal offense has the right to legal representation in court at the government's expense.  This is not true in civil immigration actions.

Comment: Edited question for past tense, since the race is over (Biden won).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here are the Democratic Presidential Candidates that definitely support repealing section 1325:

- **Bernie Sanders**: His website [says](https://berniesanders.com/issues/welcoming-and-safe-america-all/) “As president, Bernie will [r]epeal 8 U.S. Code Section 1325, putting border crossings on par with other forms of immigration violations, such as overstaying a visa.”
- **Elizabeth Warren**: Warren has long supported repealing section 1325 even before Castro proposed it in the debate, but for instance she [told](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/elizabeth-warren-immigration_n_5d1238bae4b07ae90da46c88) the Huffington Post “I agree with Secretary Castro.  We should not be criminalizing mamas and babies trying to flee violence at home or trying to build a better future.”
- **Andrew Yang**: Yang raised his hand in the June 27 debate in response to the [question](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/06/28/us/politics/transcript-debate.html) “If you'd be so kind, raise your hand if you think it should be a civil offense rather than a crime to cross the border without documentation?”
- **Tom Steyer**: Steyer [told](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/politics/policy-2020/immigration/criminal-penalties-section-1325/) the Washington Post “I support decriminalizing unauthorized border crossings. These matters are better handled through civil proceedings.

Here are the candidates who definitely oppose repealing it:

- **Joe Biden**: Biden [said](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2019/08/01/transcript-night-second-democratic-debate/) in the July 31 debate, “The fact of the matter is, you should be able to -- if you cross the border illegally, you should be able to be sent back. It's a crime. It's a crime[.]... I have guts enough to say his plan doesn't make sense. Here's the deal. The fact of the matter is that, in fact, when people cross the border illegally, it is illegal to do it unless they're seeking asylum. People should have to get in line. That's the problem. And the only reason this particular part of the law is being abused is because of Donald Trump. We should defeat Donald Trump and end this practice.”
- **Amy Klobuchar**: Klobuchar [told](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4yj8qYjbqw) ABC News “I support different enforcement priorities and of course I'll look at the statute to see if you can make changes depending on the level of a security risk, but no I don't support open borders and simply getting rid of this statute.”
- **Michael Bennet**: Bennet [told](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/politics/policy-2020/immigration/criminal-penalties-section-1325/) the Washington Post that he does not support repealing section 1325.
- **John Delaney**: Delaney [told](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/politics/policy-2020/immigration/criminal-penalties-section-1325/) the Washington Post that he does not support repealing section 1325.

And here are the candidates whose position on the issue is unclear:

- **Pete Buttigieg**: Buttigieg has been all over the map.  In the June 27 debate, in the response to the [question](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/06/28/us/politics/transcript-debate.html) “If you'd be so kind, raise your hand if you think it should be a civil offense rather than a crime to cross the border without documentation?”, Buttigieg raised his hand and said “Let's remember, that's not just a theoretical exercise. That criminalization, that is the basis for family separation. You do away with that, it's no longer possible.” But then shortly thereafter a Buttigieg spokesperson [told](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/politics/policy-2020/immigration/criminal-penalties-section-1325/) the Washington Post “No, we should not repeal all criminal penalties for crossing the border unlawfully”, and in November Buttigieg told the Washington Post “We should still have criminal penalties for people who engage in fraud or who willfully evade immigration laws.” So who knows?  But I’m guessing that a President Buttigieg would probably not try to repeal section 1325.
- **Michael Bloomberg**: Bloomberg has never addressed the issue.
- **Tulsi Gabbard**: Gabbard has never addressed the issue.
- **Deval Patrick**: Patrick has never addressed the issue.

So four support the policy, four oppose it, and four are unclear. Whew!

Comment: This confuses me on the differences between what everyone is proposing.  For example, Biden is making it sound like changing the law would result in basically being impotent when it comes to dealing with immigration violations.  Sanders on the other hand seems to suggest it would be similar to overstaying a visa; which, as far as I understand, the government is still able to deal with, including sending the ones violating it back, and potentially banning them from re-entry.  Is this a matter of wording the law differently, or do we know if someone is misrepresenting the truth?

Comment: @JMac - If it's a criminal offense, a conviction earns you prison time instead of just a fine, plus makes it much harder to legally immigrate in the future.  Biden and other proponents of sec. 1325 are saying that they believe the civil penalties aren't enough to deter people from just trying again and again until they succeed.  Opponents either believe that the civil fines are sufficient, or don't believe that illegal entry should be a crime.

Comment: @bta: "civil penalty" does not necessarily refer to a fine -- e.g. there is currently no fine for overstay

Comment: @user102008: no, but it does make one inadmissible up to 10 years. https://www.uscis.gov/legal-resources/unlawful-presence-and-bars-admissibility

Comment: @JMac The penalty against visa overstays is banning from re-entry. Banning someone who didn't enter legally in the first place from re-entry is pretty much the definition of impotent. The entry ban is a very effective deterrent against people who enter by air. It's not so effective against people who just walk across an unprotected part of the land border (and who don't necessarily care about their legal presence being able to be confirmed for things like getting a legal job or attending classes.)

Comment: @bta civil immigration violations result in inadmissibility ([8 USC 1182(a)(6)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#a_6)), so illegal entry makes it much harder to immigrate in the future regardless of whether there is a criminal conviction.

Comment: @phoog Right...but the point is, are many potential illegal immigrants really deterred by the notion that it might be harder for them to legally immigrate in the future?

Comment: @KevinCarlson probably not.  I don't suppose there are many who would be more deterred by potential criminal sanctions than they are by potential civil sanctions, either.  They know they're doing something illegal and they've decided to do it anyway.  Specific technicalities are not going to make much of a difference to their behavior.  But they do make a difference to the cost to the US of processing them (which I suspect is why the vast majority of such people are pursued for the civil violation only).

Comment: @phoog I think that’s a strong claim. Just for the sake of argument, I’m pretty sure I can imagine penalty levels that would dissuade plenty of immigration attempts.

Comment: @KevinCarlson maybe, but the levels that exist haven't been working very well, have they?  Currently there's a civil fine of $50 to $500 and a criminal fine of up to $5,000 ($250,000 for a subsequent offense) and/or imprisonment for up to six months (two years for a subsequent offense).  That's a pretty hefty penalty.  Do you think there are people who are not now deterred but would be deterred if the period of imprisonment were increased to 5 years or 10 years?

Comment: @phoog Yes, probably, assuming the penalty were applied at a high rate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103829/discussion-between-phoog-and-kevin-carlson).

Comment: @KevinCarlson Your penalties only work if the people making the decision to cross the border do so with an informed knowledge of what possible penalties they may face if caught.  I suspect many of those crossing are not lawyers and lack the means to do through research into the exact results of their failing to cross.  Your choices for deterring illegals fall into two categorizes: "mostly depend on people being deterred by what they presume you will do, regardless of your actual laws" and "do something so over the top that the US becomes infamous enough that everyone knows what happens"

Comment: @JMac to help elaborate on the different views I think most democratic candidates agree that criminal *prosecution* is usually not worth doing, ie actually forcing illegal immigrants to go to criminal trial, due to the expense/difficulty.  However, some think that criminal trials will never make sense so they should just remove the possibility so it can't be abused later.  Others think there may be some rare occasions when it makes sense to prosecute criminally so keep it just in case.  Random example maybe at some point a policy of repeat offenders being jailed but not first/second time ones.

Comment: @dsollen My model is that people have a pretty clear idea of what happens to most illegal immigrants-it’s not as if immigrants in the country are not regularly communicating back home. I don’t need to be a lawyer to know that jaywalking will not lead to imprisonment, while walking out of Costco with a large TV I haven’t paid for might.